# Passing Variables as Session Data after login

Tags: laravel, auth0

I am wondering how I could achieve the following concept. After a user logs in I am able to use a variable `Auth::user();` that returns me the currently logged in user data. I would also introduce a `Auth::myData();` ideally, or any global variable that would return me an array of my code - a simple redis attached with an user.

Questions that comes to my mind.
Due to the fact that the redis key consists of `'user.Auth::user()->name'`, and the data is a simple config array.  I wonder if each page reload / sub page would eventually turn out to trigger 1 user query and 1 redis call? If it somehow caches it should be regenerated each login(fetch)/logout(destory).
And basically where to start with this, it might be a laravel strict question, or it has to be done in the auth0lib.

For any ideas and tips appreciate.

My simple flow.

After a user logs in

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'IndexController@login']);
```

Index Controller

```
 public function login()
    {
        return \App::make('auth0')->login(null, null, ['scope' => 'openid email email_verified user_metadata profile'], 'code');
    }
```

Library I use : https://github.com/auth0/laravel-auth0

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below.. I personally use this..
Route

```
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');

Route::get('home', 'LoginController@dashboard');
```

Controller

```
use Illuminate/Services/Facades/Auth;
public function login(Request $req)
{
//logic for verify user
return redirect ('home') ;
}
```

Then you can use your Auth class like below

```
public function home()
{
$user=Auth::user() - >name;
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't be accessible in-home only, should be a global function for Auth / or other variable

Comment: Yes you can use it any where, Once the Auth::user() is registered. I just show a example...